Measure Theory - Lebesgue Measure Translation Invariant
I am self-studying Measure Theory from the book Measures, Integrals and Martingales by René L. Schilling. Could someone please help me out here? Thanks in advance!
There is this theorem (thm 5.8, pg 35) where it uses the Uniqueness Thm (thm 5.7, pg 34) to prove translation invariant of the Lebesgue Measure. I do not understand the first part of the proof. Why does $\mathbb{A}_x = \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ imply $x + B \in \mathbb{B}$? The rest of the proof is pretty obvious (using 5.7) and I have no questions regarding it, so I omitted it.
Theorem 5.8
($\mathbb{J}$ = half open intervals in R^n)
(i) The $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\lambda^n$ is invariant under translations, i.e.
$$\lambda^n(x + B) = \lambda^n(B) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n). \tag{5.3}$$
Proof:
First of all, we should convince ourselves that
$$B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \implies x + B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \tag{5.4}$$
— otherwise, the statement of Theorem 5.8 would be senseless. For this, set
$$\mathbb{A}_x := \{ B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) : x + B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \} \subseteq \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
It is clear that $\mathbb{A}_x$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that the rectangles $\mathbb{J} \subseteq \mathbb{A}_x$. Hence,
$$\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) = \sigma(\mathbb{J}) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_x \subseteq \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
and (5.4) follows. We can now start applying thm 5.7 ..........

What exactly is your question?! Please elaborate on which exact step you do not understand!!! The idea seems to be that $\mathbb{A}_x$ is a $\sigma$-algebra contained in $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and hence contains the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathbb{J}$, because $\mathbb{J} \subset \mathbb{A}_x$ .

Edited. You can have a look now.


Why does $\mathbb{A}_x=\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ imply $x+B\in\mathbb{B}$?

If we knew that $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_x$,then it follows that $B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \implies B \in \mathbb{A}_x \implies x + B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, by definition of $\mathbb{A}_x$. So once we have that $\mathbb{A}_x = \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we are done.
To see why this doesn't follow directly from just knowing that $\mathbb{A}_x \subseteq \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, notice that $\mathbb{A}_x$ refers only to the members $B$ of $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for which $x + B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. it could be the case that there is some $B \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for which $x + B \not\in \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. This is why we still need to prove that $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_x$.
